# Assigning text for a textbox when the selecting a value from dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, dropdownbox

I want to change the text of a textbox  based on  the value selected in the dropdown. This is the code i wrote

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 3;


    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Manager")

        TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(a);

    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "Front office")
        TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(b);

}
```

When i select the value from the drop down the value doesn't change in the text box.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Has your DropDownList1 AutoPostBack property set to true? if not, set it to true and retry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you set "AutoPostBack" to true on your `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:DropDownList = runat="server" ID= "DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Unlike with desktop applications, the code you write in your event handlers won't fire until the aspx page posts back to the server (refreshes).